# Can't get System.Numerics to work with command-line Mono (mcs) on OS X

Tags: mono, pkg-config

We're trying to run a simple Mono script on the command line on OS X.  Most scripts work fine for us, but as soon as we try to use System.Numerics, we get "error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Numerics' does not exist in the namespace System."

This isn't too surprising, and should be fixable with an appropriate command-line option to mcs, plus properly set up PKG_CONFIG_PATH... but this is where we get stumped.  First, here's the script so you can follow along at home:

```
using System;
using System.Numerics;

public static class MainProgram {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

So next we tried "mcs -r:System.Numerics Test.cs".  This produces "error CS0006: Metadata file `System.Numerics' could not be found".

"man mcs" suggests that we can get the other system packages by adding "-pkg:dotnet" to the command line.  But that produces:

> Package dotnet was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps
>   you should add the directory containing `dotnet.pc' to the
>   PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable No package 'dotnet' found error
>   CS8027: Error running pkg-config. Check the above output.

OK then, we had no PKG_CONFIG_PATH, so we tried defining one:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/pkgconfig/
```

This fixes the CS8027; but we still get the CS0234 we started with.  And if I combine the -pkg and the -r, e.g. "mcs -pkg:dotnet -r:System.Numerics Test.cs", I get "error CS0006: Metadata file `System.Numerics' could not be found".

I'm stumped at this point... any idea what incantation I'm missing to make System.Numerics work with mcs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Mono 2.10.x, you will have to compile with `dmcs` rather than `mcs` to enable the 4.0 profile (System.Numerics is a C# 4.0+ feature only).

If you're using Mono 2.11.x or 3.0.x, then `mcs` by default should select the 4.5 profile. `mcs -help` should show `2`, `4`, and `4.5` as possible values for the -sdk option.  If it doesn't, then the framework isn't properly installed; I had that once, where I think that `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current` pointed to the wrong directory; installing a second time fixed that.

Manipulating `pkg-config` should be unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you!  mcs --version shows that I'm running 2.10.12.0.  It does have a -sdk option, which defaults to 2, and supposedly allows 4, but when I try -sdk:4, I get a pageful of errors.  But dmcs works fine, and so we'll just stick to that until we upgrade to Mono 2.11.x or later.  We were really stumped on this one -- thanks for your help!